# SQL Server: most commonly used data types?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a bit confused as there are many variable types in sql server (ntext, varchar, nvarchar, etc) so maybe if you give me what data types you use for the following fields I'll understand this a little better. If I'm missing a common field type please let me know.

ID
Telephone Number
Email
Description (a paragraph of text)
Name
SSN
Price
Ship Date
Sex (m/f)
Discontinued (yes/no)
Quantity
Zip Code

Comment: If your application is targeting a world-wide audience I would recommend using the Unicode string types (`nchar`, `nvarchar`) instead of the older 8-bit types (`char`, `varchar`) for anything that is entered by, or displayed to, the user.

Answer (score 11):

A brief recommendation:

- `TEXT, NTEXT, IMAGE`: all those types are **deprecated** and scheduled to be removed in a future version of SQL Server - **don't use those!**
- `CHAR` vs. `VARCHAR`: `CHAR` is fixed-length, and it will be padding inputs with spaces to the defined length. Works best for short strings (< 5 characters), e.g. codes, like currency (almost always 3 characters), US status (2 chars) etc. `VARCHAR` on the other hand works best for longer strings and is only storing as much characters as are inserted/updated. If you define a `VARCHAR(200)` and only insert `Christmas` into the field, your field occupies 9 characters (and a litte bit of overhead)
- `NCHAR/NVARCHAR`: Unicode versions of the above; always stores 2 bytes per characters, so your field with `Christmas` in it will store 9 characters and use 18 bytes to do so. Those are needed if you have non-Western-European characters - such as Cyrillic, Arabic, Hebrew, Asian or other alphabets.
- `VARCHAR(MAX) / NVARCHAR(MAX)` are the replacements for `TEXT` and `NTEXT` - storing up to 2 GByte (2 billion bytes) of data - that's over 300 times the content of Tolstoi's `War and Peace` - should suffice for the **vast** majority of cases :-)

So your decision tree could be like this:

1. Do I need non-Western-European characters? If yes --> use `NCHAR/NVARCHAR` types, otherwise `CHAR/VARCHAR`
2. Is my string very short (< 5 characters) and typically always the same length? If yes: use CHAR, otherwise VARCHAR
3. Do I need really really huge volumes of text? If so, use VARCHAR(MAX), otherwise size it to match your needs

Comment: I have a table named class that contains two columns ClassId and Class. I would store only 12 records in that table. e.g: IX, X, XI, XII, BCom-I etc. My Question: what datatype would you suggest me for my ClassId columns and why?

Comment: +1, perhaps worth adding your view on choosing the most appropriate out of decimal/numeric, real and float.

Answer (score 6):

```
Field -> Data Type
-----    ---------
Id       int
Phone #  varchar
Email    varchar
Desc     varchar
Name     varchar
Ssn      varchar
Price    decimal, money, smallmoney
ShipDate datetime
Sex      bit
Discont  bit
Quantity int
ZipCode  varchar
```

Comment: I have a table named class that contains two columns ClassId and Class. I would store only 12 records in that table. e.g: IX, X, XI, XII, BCom-I etc. My Question: what datatype would you suggest me for my ClassId columns and why?

Comment: @kashif - If you already know there will only be 12 items, and you know exactly what those items are going to be, I probably wouldn't put them in a database at all. If I had to choose, though, I would certainly chose an int column for the id.

Comment: I Actually Have a Students database. I bind my Class table with a combobox and keep column class in Class table as display member and ClassId as value memeber. in my studentInfo table I use a clumns ClassId i.e StudentInfo.ClassId with a foreign key to Class.ClassId. I hope now you understand my situation

Comment: What about keeping the Class.ClassId column as byte as byte occupies less memory in database as compared to int? I currently have its datatype numeric(2,0)

Answer (score 2):

```
ID - int
Telephone - varchar(12)
email - varchar(size)
descripion varchar(max)
name -varchar(size)
ssn - varchar(11)
price - smallmoney (or money if needed)
shipdate - date (for sql server 2008, or smalldatetime for pre-2008)
discontinued - bit
quanity - int
zipcode - varchar(10)
```

A lot of folks are going to recommend nvarchar in all cases instead of varchar, but knowing my sites/audience, I don't need to allow for international character sets and don't want to waste the space/speed/resources (minimal I know). If you need to, then substitute nvarchar where appropriate

Comment: i see everyone uses varchar for the SSN, is it because you want to store the hyphen?

Comment: A rule of thumb I was taught years ago (and its worked well) a number field is for data that may have arithmetic done on it.  A phone number or ID (SSN) number is not a factor to a calculation but rather a string of characters.  The characters happen to be all numeric but that's not particularly important.

Comment: I would argue against a string for a value that is known to always be numeric, and is likely to be searched against. An integer type will index better (and create a smaller index too). I'd also use a longer field for the phone number to allow for international formats (ITU requires at least 16, including the leading "+").

Comment: But if you're allowing for international phone nos then, perhaps, you should allow for international SSN types too, which are not entirely numeric. eg UK NI number, not quite as useful as SSN but also not solely numeric - "AA 99 99 99 A".

Comment: Any 'numeric value' where leading zeros are important and not inferred by length should be varchar as otherwise the zeros will be lost.

Comment: To @PaulGregory's point, both SSNs and Zip codes can definitely start with a leading 0, which will be lost if stored as an int.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have used in the past

```
ID = bigint 
Telephone = varchar(12)
Email = varchar(100)
Description = nvarchar(max) (sql Server 2005 and 2008 only)
Name = nvarchar(100)
SSN = varchar(11)
Price = money
ShipDate = datetime (date if using SQL Server 2008)
Sex = char(1) (i have also used bit before 0 = female 1 =male)
Discontinued (true false field) = bit
Quantity = int if not fractional decimal if it is fractional
ZipCode = varchar(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ID                     int or bigint
Telephone Number       varchar
Email                  varchar
Description            varchar
Name                   varchar
SSN                    varchar
Price                  money
Ship Date              datetime or date
Sex (m/f)              char(1)
Discontinued (yes/no)  bit
Quantity               int
Zip Code               varchar
```